# c# Programing looping

Tags: c#

So here is my code. I want the user to enter a number between 1-4 and if he doesn't, I want to make sure the user goes back to the top to restart the lottery.

```
   Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Lottery game.");
    Console.WriteLine("Guess three numbers between 1-4");
    Random ranNumberGenerator = new Random();
    int random1, guess1;
    int matches = 0;
    const int min = 1, max = 4;
    random1 = ranNumberGenerator.Next(min, max);

    Console.Write("First Guess Lottery Number is:", min, max);
     guess1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

How do I make sure if he enters a number 5 or bigger. It ask him to try again and go back to "Console.Write("First Guess Lottery Number:", min, max);" Its a basic programming class. Please keep it simple nothing to fancy. He told us to use while or something like that...

Comment: Didn't you ask essentially this [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595091/c-sharp-programming-looping-back-to-the-top) a few hours ago? Rather than just reposting the same question, you should edit your original question to include the relevant information.

Comment: I DID LOL but no one answered it clearly lol

Comment: @user3625962 Yes they did.. you even said "you're a life saver". Perhaps refer to your notes from class?

Comment: Well to be fair that was on a different kind of question. ;) But yes, this user needs to study more. I have sympathy though, programming doesn't come easily to everyone.

Comment: It's your homework and you're not even trying.  At the very least show us some sort of effort by implementing a loop.  It might not execute properly, but then we'd have something to work with.

Comment: @eshs I'm sympathetic, too. I understand that programming is hard, especially for those starting out, but OP really needs to show *some* research effort. https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+Programing+looping

Comment: it takes me like 15 minutes to look everything up. I thought it would be easier to just ask people...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
while (guess < 1 || guess > 4)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number between 1 and 4: ");
    guess = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

This will prompt the user to enter a number that's converted into an Int32 and stored in guess1 until the user answers a number that is not less than 1 or greater than 4.

At the end of the while loop, the conditionals inside of the parentheses are evaluated to see if either returns as true. If either returns true, the contents of the while loop are executed. If not, the code continues from the end of the brackets.

Thus if we store a value in guess *inside the while-loop* and use it for the conditional, we can have the code only exit when guess has a certain value read into it. In this case, the while loop is executed as long as guess is less than 1 or greater than 4. If it ever becomes greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 4, the while loop finishes and code execution continues after the last bracket.

Use this knowledge and the code example I gave you to finish your assignment.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to make it less of a hand out. The original answer I gave was incorrect anyways since I had only skimmed his question.

Comment: haha ya thanks you! How do you guys just know these stuff without even taking the class. Its so hard for me and I have to look up everything.. Its a pain in the ass..

Comment: @user3625962 Who said we don't take classes?  I have a degree in Computer Programming and I'm constantly on Plurasight.  Knowledge is power.